# Is epilepsy more heritable from maternal side?

Tags: genetics

I am thinking if paternal or maternal genetic line is the risk factor. 
Mitochondrial DNA is coming from maternal line. 
I do not know the pathogenesis of epilepsy so well that I could answer my question.

**Is epilepsy more heritable from the maternal side?**

Answer (score 3):

Epilepsy is a neurological disorder characterized by hypersynchronous discharge of neurons .i.e abnormal electrical activity in the brain. Epileptic seizures caused primarily due to i) inhibition of inhibitory neurotransmitter systems such GABA neurotransmitters or ii) Enhancement of excitatory neurotransmitter systems such as nAchR. These conditions arise due to head injury, trauma and genetic factors. But there is no evidence as of now regarding Mitochondrial DNA taking part in inhibitory and excitatory systems. so, epileptic seizures are not specific in inheriting from any side (Maternal or paternal side) as far as pathophysiology of epilepsy is concerned.

Comment: I am thinking about the genetic factors, since more genetic factors are inherited from the maternal side because of mitochondrial DNA. If mitochondria play any role in the disease, then maternal side has more role in the pathology of the disease. I have seen one case where the disease spread only through maternal genetics - and do not understand this.